# Jupyter iPython Notebook and Command Line yield different results

Tags: python

I have the following Python 2.7 code:

```
def average_rows2(mat):
    '''
    INPUT: 2 dimensional list of integers (matrix)
    OUTPUT: list of floats

    Use map to take the average of each row in the matrix and
    return it as a list.

    Example:
    >>> average_rows2([[4, 5, 2, 8], [3, 9, 6, 7]])
    [4.75, 6.25]
    '''
    return map(lambda x: sum(x)/float(len(x)), mat)
```

When I run it in my browser using iPython notebook, I get the following output:

```
[4.75, 6.25]
```

However, when I run the code's file on Command Line (Windows), I get the following error:

```
>python -m doctest Delete.py

**********************************************************************
File "C:\Delete.py", line 10, in Delete.average_rows2
Failed example:
    average_rows2([[4, 5, 2, 8], [3, 9, 6, 7]])
Expected:
    [4.75, 6.25]
Got:
    <map object at 0x00000228FE78A898>
**********************************************************************
```

Why does the command line toss an error? Is there a better way to structure my function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like your command line is running Python 3. The builtin `map` returns a list in Python 2, but an iterator (a `map` object) in Python 3. To turn the latter into a list, apply the `list` constructor to it:

```
# Python 2
average_rows2([[4, 5, 2, 8], [3, 9, 6, 7]]) == [4.75, 6.25]
# => True

# Python 3
list(average_rows2([[4, 5, 2, 8], [3, 9, 6, 7]])) == [4.75, 6.25]
# => True
```